# Sublime Text can't find external C++ libraries

Tags: c++, sublimetext2, sublimetext, sublimetext3, openframeworks

I've been looking for an answer to this for about a week now, but I can't find one anywhere. I'm using openFrameworks with Sublime Text on Windows 8, and I've installed MinGW and added it to the path. I've also installed SublimeClang and added this to my SublimeClang User Settings:

```
{
"options": [ 
    "-I/laura/openFrameworks/libs/**",
    "-I/laura/openFrameworks/addons/**"
]
```

}

The error I'm getting is:

```
/laura/openFrameworks/apps/myApps/mySketch/src/ofApp.h:3:10: 
fatal error: 'ofMain.h' file not found
#include "ofMain.h"
         ^
1 error generated.
[Finished in 0.1s with exit code 1]
```

So I don't know if it's a SublimeClang problem or a Sublime problem or a Windows problem, but I'm also new to C++ and don't entirely understand how it builds or finds things. Do I have to addopenFrameworks/libs to the path too or something?

Thanks

Comment: where is the ofMain.h file ? In C++ (and C) the compiler needs to have explicit direction to find the files that you include. You need to specifiy to the compiler the directory in which the .h file is. (this is what "-I" options mean : add the directory to the "Include" path.

Comment: It's in openFrameworks/libs/openFrameworks. I thought including "-I/laura/openFrameworks/libs/**" added all subdirectories?

Comment: Ok. First of all Sublime Clang is a plugin to use clang (a compiler based on LLVM) to provide auto-completion and code analysis in sublime for C\C++ languages. You don't use clang, you use MinGW which is a port of GCC to Windows, so forget Sublime-Clang altogether, or install LLVM/Clang, but I don't know how well it is supported on Windows.

Answer (score 2):

NB: Sublime text is an editor. It doesn't have a dedicated build system, or any language integration per se. It just provides convenient ways to call external Build systems via hotkeys (CTRL + B)

Your problem is with the Build system.
Sublime Text 2's default build system for c++ is just calling g++ in command line.
That is sufficient for Hello World, but to build an application that leverages 3rd party libraries, you need an actual Build system, such as make.
Sublime text has a default support for make (you just select the `make` options in Tools/Build Systems)
The problem with make is that you need to write your own makefile, which is quite beyond the scope of your c++ knowledge apparently (don't take this bad)

You have 3 options in my opinion :

1. Learn to write makefiles and use Sublime text (with `make` Build system option or make from the command line)
2. Use some other (simpler and nicer) build system built on top of make such as CMake. There is a package CMake (that provides syntax highlighting for CMake language) and another CMake-snippets, that provides snippets (prototypes) for the most common operations.
3. Switch from Sublime text to an IDE. Since you are on windows I suggest QtCreator or Visual Studio Express. I prefer Qt Creator. The good thing about Qt Creator is that it provides its own Build system (qmake) that is very well integrated with the editor, and very noob friendly.

Of course you will learn exponentially more going the 1 or 2nd options, and you'll be up and running in 5 minutes with the 3rd. Your call.
Note that if you want to become a pro c++ developper you will have to learn about Build Systems eventually.